# I could not display the employee's name, tasks, and date via the ListView(Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I made two tables, the first stores the names of the employees, and the second stores the duties and the date.
But I could not display the name of the employee, the duties assigned to him, and the date.
This is my code, hope you can help me.

```
public class MyTabels
{
    [Table("Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [OneToMany]
        public List<Duty> Duties { get; set; }
    }


    [Table("Duties")]
    public class Duty
    {

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Employee))]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This XAML There is an CollectionView and I have added items into it:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="CV" IsGrouped="True">
            <CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Large"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding LastName}" FontSize="Large"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Deadline}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

This My Code:

```
var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Mydb.db");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
        db.CreateTable<Employee>();
        db.CreateTable<Duty>();
var employee = new Employee
        {
            Name = "Andrew",
            LastName = "Programmer"
        };
        db.Insert(employee);


        var duty1 = new Duty()
        {
            Description = "Project A Management",
            Deadline = new DateTime(2017, 10, 31)
        };

        var duty2 = new Duty()
        {
            Description = "Reporting work time",
            Deadline = new DateTime(2022, 12, 31)
        };

        db.Insert(duty1);
        db.Insert(duty2);

        employee.Duties = new List<Duty> { duty1, duty2 };
        db.UpdateWithChildren(employee);

        var employeeStored = db.GetWithChildren<Employee>(employee.Id);

        CV.ItemsSource = employeeStored.Duties;
```

Comment: 1. CollectionView does not use Cell types in templates.  Only ListView uses them.  2. have you verified that you are getting data from your db query?  3. You are using a Grouped CollectionView, but your data is not formatted for grouping.

Comment: 4. `var employeeStored` - If you hover over "var" (or change to "explicit type"), what is the exact type shown? (It needs to be some collection type - won't work if it is simply "Employee".). And verify that employeeStored contains the values you expect.

Comment: 5. "This My Code:" - how does that get called?  During constructor, or onappearing, or some user action (e.g. in a button click)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new class to convert the data you get from the database match the CollectionView ItemSource.

Model:

```
public class EmployeeList : List<Duty>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public EmployeeList(string name, string lastName, List<Duty> duties) : base(duties)
    {
        Name = name;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Usage: Use GetAllWithChildren to get all the employees into list from the database.

```
       public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{
    public List<EmployeeList> employeeStored { get; set; } = new List<EmployeeList>();

    public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Mydb.db");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
        db.CreateTable<Employee>();
        db.CreateTable<Duty>();
        var employee = new Employee
        {
            Name = "Andrew",
            LastName = "Programmer"
        };
        db.Insert(employee);


        var duty1 = new Duty()
        {
            Description = "Project A Management",
            Deadline = new DateTime(2017, 10, 31)
        };

        var duty2 = new Duty()
        {
            Description = "Reporting work time",
            Deadline = new DateTime(2022, 12, 31)
        };

        db.Insert(duty1);
        db.Insert(duty2);

        employee.Duties = new List<Duty> { duty1, duty2 };
        db.UpdateWithChildren(employee);

        //var employeeStored2 = db.GetWithChildren<Employee>(employee.Id);

        var employeeStored = db.GetAllWithChildren<Employee>();

        
        var list = Convert(employeeStored);
        CV.ItemsSource = list;
        this.BindingContext = this;

    }
    public List<EmployeeList> Convert(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        foreach (var item in employees)
        {
            employeeStored.Add(new EmployeeList(item.Name, item.LastName, item.Duties));
        }
        return employeeStored;

    }


}
```

And note that CollectionView has no concept of cells. So delete it in your Xaml.

**Update:**

Xaml:

```
      <CollectionView  x:Name="CV" IsGrouped="True">
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding  Name}" FontSize="Large"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding LastName}" FontSize="Large"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                 
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Deadline}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for helping me, I followed your steps perfectly, and show me an error("System.InvalidOperationException: 'LoadTemplate should not be null'")
Can you explain the last step related to XAML

Comment: I have updated the reply with Xaml. Please check it.

Comment: Awesome, I'm grateful to you.  But I'm a beginner at Xamarin.forms, and I'm having a hard time learning the relationships between tables.  I can't find educational resources on the internet, can you help me?

Comment: For the database, you could refer to the docs for normal use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases For the relationships between tables, you could search with sqlite database one to many, one to one and many to many for more details.